# Application Transaction

Tags: .net, transactions, transactionscope, 3-tier

How to use application transaction in 3 tier architecture using .net?
Is application transaction similar to transaction scope?If they are different,then what's the difference?

Comment: You asked pretty much the same question tice. Why?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly long read, but full of good information on how to use transactions in .NET with SQL Server and Oracle:

[DB Concurrency Control with .NET – Overview](http://petermeinl.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/db-concurrency-control-with-net/).